# Reporting Cell based on number from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I have a group of 400 proxies in column C. 
I would like a formula that would report a random list of the proxies (from C) to column A and B based on the number in cell A1 and B1

```
A1  B1 C1:C400

10  20 Proxy List
```

So based on the number in Row 1 I would like a list to pop up of that many proxies and in a random order.

So if A1 is 10 I would like 10 proxies from the proxy like to pop up starting in A2. Also I would like it so that these proxies are not used more than one time so there will not be the same proxies in Row A and B.

In each column I would like the proxies from AF to be placed there based on the amounts in row 1 and I would like these proxies to only be used one time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have a somewhat complex question and you show absolutely **no** effort at solving it yourself. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about how to receive the most effective help on the site and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: `code` =INDEX(C2:C400,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS(C2:C400)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS(C2:C400‌​),COLUMNS(C2:C400))+1 `code`

Comment: Also this is for the random part `code`=INDEX($C:$C,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($C:$C)),1)`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this without VBA is to use the formula you have an conditional formatting.

Since `RANDBETWEEN` is a volatile function you can use conditional formatting to show any duplicate values that show up and then just re-calculate the list until you do not see duplicates.

See below:

[image]

A2 and B2 have the formula: `=IF(ROW()<=A$1,INDEX($C:$C,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($C:$C)),1),"")` *change to B$1 for column B*

Drag these formulas down for as many rows as you think you may need to cover for a  given value in A1 and / or B1.

Then apply the following rules for Duplicate Values in Conditional Formatting Wizard. First rule is for cells that contain blanks (make sure to step `Stop If True` - this will stop blank cells from showing as duplicates`.

[image]

Then if duplicates exist in column A and/or B, you will see them easily:

[image]

**CAVEAT** - this works well with smaller numbers in A1 and B1, but fails a bit with larger numbers of IP addresses, since the randomness of the formula creates more duplicates.

Comment: ive gotten this for the random part but it is only working in cell A2 after that I get #REF

Comment: @brainkanback - please read my entire post again (I made some edits). you have to account for dupes with the `randbetween`. My method works decently, but fails if you want larger lists of IP addresses. Otherwise, VBA is probably the way to go.

Comment: @brainkanback - glad it worked. make sure to read my edited answer. I adjusted it to make it better. if it solves your problem, please mark as answered so others know going forward.

Comment: Hello I switched this formula to my actual file with this code `code`=IF(ROW()<=CU$6,INDEX($GF:$GF,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($GF:$GF)),1),"")`code`  for the number I want shown i put 9 and only 1 proxy shows up then I try 10 and only 2 show up I put the formula in cell CU9